# Fetching first child data all the time in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Hello Every one i'm creating an app in which i'm trying to fetch user(logged in user)data and wants to show his profile detail. 
But i'm confuse that why firebase giving me latest created child data all time, although i need current logged in user's data. As picture showing database structure under **"Caller Data"**

Data which is retrieving is correct but it is not data of actual current user but it is of latest registered user.please help me i'm stuck here.
[image: Structure of database in firebase]

actually i create two android app in one project of firebase. I also try make child id by user email but firebase not support itperhaps. it creating problem then i try to save by Phone number its working correctly. 
[image: complete database]

**.java file code is here**

**Here i'm trying to fetch data in onStart method**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.OnlineRescueSystem.Model.Registration;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "ProfileActivity";
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    private CircleImageView profileImage;
    private TextView namePofile,addressP,phoneNumberP,emailP;
    private String mName,mPhoneNumber,mEmail,mAddress;
    private String mImage;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;
    private FirebaseUser mUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        // Write a message to the database
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("Caller Data");


        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        namePofile = findViewById(R.id.CNICEditTextID_profile);
        addressP = findViewById(R.id.nameEditTextID_profile);
        phoneNumberP = findViewById(R.id.phonNoID_profile);
        emailP = findViewById(R.id.passwordID_profile);
        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profileImage_profile);

    }  // end of on create


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.logout_profile, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_logout:
                mAuth.signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,LoginScreen.class));
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Registration registration = dataSnapshot.getValue(Registration.class);

                // showing progress dialog
                mProgress.setMessage("please wait.. ");
                mProgress.show();

                //fetching data from database
                mName = registration.getName();
                mPhoneNumber = registration.getPhoneNumber();
                mEmail = registration.getEmail();
                mAddress = registration.getAddress();
                mImage =registration.getImage();

                namePofile.setText(mName);
                phoneNumberP.setText(mPhoneNumber);
                emailP.setText(mEmail);
                addressP.setText(mAddress);


                ///profileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.accidentview);


                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(registration.getImage().toString()).into(profileImage);

                //Picasso.get().load(registration.getImage()).into(profileImage);
                //Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mImage).into(profileImage);
                //profileImage.setImageResource(mImage);
                mProgress.dismiss();
//                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"1st here"+mImage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }// end of onStart
}// end of class
```

**.xml file code is here**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    //layout colored with blue background
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/outerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        tools:context=".RegisterActivity"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        //profile picture circle view
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileImage_profile"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        //plus icon below profile picture
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/plusIcon_profile"
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="195dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="130dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    ////layout colored with Ehite background
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lowerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="390dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        //Layout with person name Icon and text field
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_of_linearview"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhiteGray">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/personIcon_profile"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_of_icon"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CNICEditTextID_profile"
                android:text="your name..."
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_of_textView"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textView_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        //Layout with CNIC Icon and text field
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_of_linearview"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhiteGray">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/CNICIcon_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_of_icon"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_credit_card_black_24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phonNoID_profile"
                android:text="03..."
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_of_textView"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textView_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        //Layout with phon Icon and text field
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_of_linearview"
            android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhiteGray">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/phonNoIcon_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_of_icon"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/passwordID_profile"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_of_textView"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="your email..."
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textView_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        //Layout with Address Icon and text field
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_of_linearview"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhiteGray">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/AddressIcon_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_of_icon"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameEditTextID_profile"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_of_textView"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="your address..."
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textView_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you will get all the data you need to iterate and get the exact data that you need. your data snapshot will have all users data

Comment: how to filter it ?

Comment: how to iterate it to fetch individual user?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead of that Registration thing.

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "ProfileActivity";
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;

private CircleImageView profileImage;
private TextView nameProfile,addressP,phoneNumberP,emailP;
private String mName,mPhoneNumber,mEmail,mAddress;
private String mImage;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
//private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;
//private FirebaseUser mUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String num2 = intent.getStringExtra("Phone Number");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),num2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    nameProfile = findViewById(R.id.CNICEditTextID_profile);
    addressP = findViewById(R.id.nameEditTextID_profile);
    phoneNumberP = findViewById(R.id.phonNoID_profile);
    emailP = findViewById(R.id.passwordID_profile);
    profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profileImage_profile);

    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Caller Data").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                try {
                    mName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    mEmail = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                    mAddress = dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue().toString();
                    mPhoneNumber = dataSnapshot.child("phoneNumber");

                    nameProfile.setText(mName);
                    emailP.setText(mEmail);
                    addressP.setText(mAddress);
                    phoneNumberP.setText(mPhoneNumber);

                }catch (Throwable e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(get application context, databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

}  // end of on create
```

}

Please remove the `onStart(); fucntion` and try this code. This works for me.

Comment: i try with your method. Its showing nullPointerException:

Comment: @Hannan can you show me the complete database once please? That's because the path maybe incorrect. And also please show me that null pointer Exception. I need to see what's null?

Comment: actually its snapshot returning me complete database or last entered child. Its showing me last child values. Last time i entered null values in database and because its become last child of my database and than its showing null pointer exception. Now i delete last child(which contain null values) then out put screen showing me second last child(which become last child after deleting last).

Comment: https://github.com/hannan228/UserRegistrationAndloging   (here i uploaded my code in git hub )

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
This types

Comment: following exception i'm gettingbro. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Sure give me some time looking at it

Comment: @Hannan please try my updated code. I have removed the onStart(), please try it my way

Comment: No bro. again same exception

Comment: Share a screenshot of error from Android studio. I want to see which line is error

Comment: @Hannan please check my code again, myRef was defined 2  times so i corrected it. Try one if error persists then share screenshot of android studio error. Please try to use exact code as mine. I corrected a few incorrect spelling like pofile to profile so that may cause error and everything is case sensitive.

Comment: @Hannan you cannot use Uid in your database. .child("Caller Data").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() doesn't work.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir That works for me though. But his UIDs in database looks wierd starting with -M , are those user UID?? If yes, my code works. But if those aren't UID then it will fail

Comment: @Hannan please share screenshot of your full database, I want to check the parent nodes.

Comment: Those are not UID. just database unique key. @Dharmaraj your code is working but not with this db.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir can you say how do we get Database unique keys??

Comment: You cannot  get this way. You can get list of caller this way. @Hannan have to change the DB if you want to get own user.

Comment: @Hannan can you replace those databse unique IDs with Users Authentication UIDS?? Please that would be great and easy

Comment: Ok bro i'm trying

Comment: @Dharmaraj i edit my post with screen shot of WHOLE DATABASE.

Comment: @Hannan please check this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/2DMeKZi) . Can you please try using User UID as that node value instead of that database ID?? This will be good

Comment: @Dharmar i solved it. Uid are changing automatically so i use gmail by replacing dot(.) from gmail account.

Comment: @Hannan glad  to know. You can post the answer and accept it so everyone knows its solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do similar to shown below:

You can have a unique id for each user. You need to know the `id` of the `user` that is the owner of the device.

Later Based on `Id` you can get his detail and `filter` when your firebase listener is called:

```
User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

based on Id you can filter and check if he is the logged in user

```
if (user.id.equals(loogedInUser.id)){
fetch the data and display.
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I try to generate child id, by getting user id, through getUid() method. But it not working correctly, because user id changed automatically. i save data through gmail as child id but due to dot('.'), in gmail account, also not works because dot(.) is not allowed in child id. So, i use gmail by following method 
**i find dot and remove it from user gmail and save user data by his gmail id as child  id as following**

```
  final int i = email.indexOf(".");  //it tell on what index dot(.) is existing.
    PostDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Database name").child(email.substring(0,i))
```

**and in another class where i wwants to get user data from firebase i get email by following method**

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String email = mUser.getUemail 
String subEmail = mUser.getEmail();
```

**this is how i get database reference and reference of child where i wants to retrieve user data.**

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("Database name").child(subEmail.substring(0,subEmail.indexOf(".")));
```